# ng-grid column level filtering with substring search

Tags: ng-grid

I have looked at this plunker.

```
http://plnkr.co/edit/WJzTr8AR8dhWIjXELNY1?p=preview
```

It filters on first characters. Has anyone attempted to perform this filtering based on a substring search. If so please let me know

I worked on modifying the filter text as shown

```
angular.forEach(filterBarPlugin.scope.columns, function(col) {
                if (col.visible && col.filterText) {
                    var filterText = (col.filterText.indexOf('*') == 0 ? col.filterText.replace('*', '') : col.filterText + "^") + ";";
                    searchQuery += col.displayName + ": " + filterText;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

The original plunkr is design filtering from the beginning characters. If you went to filtering from the substring, you can try `*` begin filter textbox.

If you don't like it, you can modify `filterBarPlugin` function :

```
var filterText = (col.filterText.indexOf('*') == 0 ? col.filterText.replace('*', '') : "^" + col.filterText) + ";";
searchQuery += col.displayName + ": " + filterText;
```

To

```
var filterText = col.filterText +'; ';
searchQuery += col.displayName + ": " + filterText;
```

[Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/tUIEJ4lKVMvQnKiVjgHx?p=preview)

updated: fixed not allow for multiple column sorting, thanks **@mainguy**

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an answer but more an update to **@allyusd**'s answer.

He is basically right, but his wildcardless solution does not allow for multi column sorting because a semicolon is missing.

With these small changes:

```
angular.forEach(filterBarPlugin.scope.columns, function(col) {
            if (col.visible && col.filterText) {
                var filterText = col.filterText +'; ';
                searchQuery += col.displayName + ": " + filterText;
            }
        });
```

you can filter in this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZzG9SuDZkBCu3bffdYds?p=preview) for `name=or` **AND** `age=4` and you will get **Enors** as result.

As I said: Just an update, kudos to allyusd!